# Implementation of previous() and hasPrevious() method in a doubly linked lists

Tags: java, iterator, doubly-linked-list

I am writing a `doubly linked list` with an iterator. I managed to implement the `next()` and the `hasNext()`methods. It works fine, and I am getting the expected result after a forward traversing. But I am stuck in how to implement `previous()` and `hasPrevious()`. Here what I did:

```
private class ListIterator<E> implements java.util.ListIterator<E> { 
        private Node<E> current = (Node<E>) head;
        private Node<E> last = (Node<E>) tail;

        public ListIterator() {

        }

        public ListIterator(int index) {
            if (index < 0 || index > size)
                  throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
                for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
                  current = current.next;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return (current != null);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasPrevious() {
            return  last != null;
        }

        @Override
        public E next() {  
            E e = current.element;
            current = current.next;
            return e;
        }

        @Override
        public E previous() {
            E e = (E) last.element;
            last = last.previous;
            return e;
        }
```

I am getting just the last element in my `List` when I want a backwards traversing:

```
[11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5] //list
 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 //Forward traversing 
 5   //Backwards traversing
```

What I am doing wrong? Why can't I traverse backwards through the whole `List`?

Comment: It looks like `tail.previous` is `null`.  The code you have here looks good;  I would take a look at the code where you construct your list and double-check that `previous` is getting set correctly when you add elements.

Comment: @azurefrog: I am using a while-loop: ` while(itr.hasPrevious()) {
       System.out.print(itr.previous() + " ");`. But I am getting just the last. It starts good. I don't understand!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason to track the last element. Just current one. You could implement previous() using current.previous

Comment: do you mean like that: `public E previous() {
   E e = (E) current.element;
   current = current.previous;
   return e;`

Comment: yes, exactly like this. By the way isn't `private Node<E> current = (Node<E>) head;` this cast and cast in `previous()` method useless?